# Call class from server side in client side

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I have class in server side and I want use method of this class in client side. How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to look at the basics of how the communication of the client application works with the server.

All server side functionality has to be exposed as a service/RPC based functionality in GWT.

If you look at the tutorial at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.5/tutorial/RPC.html, you have to do the following.

For your requirement, you have to create another **method** (except the methods you already have created), so do the following:

- Define the service – in the interface which extends RemoteService interface
- Implementing the service – in the class which extends RemoteServiceServlet class and implements the service defined interface
- Implements the server-side – in the class which extends RemoteServiceServlet and implements the service defined interface

Hope this would help.